# Post ajax requests parameters are sometimes sent in the wrong format to rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

My problem is so weird:

1. I have this form:

   ```
   <form id="my-form" method="post" action="/password_reset/update/<%= @user.perishable_token %>" charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="password" name="user[password]" class="required" minlength="6" />
     <input type="password" name="user[password_confirmation]" class="required" equalto="#password-field" minlength="6" />
     <input type="hidden" name="page" value="set" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
   ```
2. The client send an ajax request to my rails server (using jquery 1.6.1, jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.1, jQuery Form Plugin 2.67)

   ```
   $("#my-form").validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
       $(form).ajaxSubmit();
     }
   });
   ```
3. The server side receives the request and here is the probleme. Sometimes:

   - Instead of get parameters with the expected format as below

     `Parameters: {"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "page"=>"set", "id"=>"bFC7bkz6tzOF4i2KXZ"}`
   - ... I get:

     `Parameters: {"_json"=>"user%5Bpassword%5D=password&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=password&page=set", "id"=>"perishable_token"}`

I tested the form in lots of cases (with different browsers/OS) and it's impossible to me to reproduce this problem. I can just see it in my production rails log.

**So my questions are:**

- Why this problem can happen ?
- How can I reproduce this bug ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Definitely has something to do with how the jQuery plugin works or the way you have it setup. Try using firebug or the dev tools in chrome to inspect the headers made from the XHR request. See how the data is formatted going to it. If everything is in the _json value.

Answer (score 0):

Try set datatype, that you want:

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({dataType=>"desirable format"});
```

format may be "xml", "script" or "json"